# Can we make a parameter compulsory on conditions?

Tags: flutter, dart

As we know we can use ternary operator like `?` and `:` in Dart for control flow, like :

```
String name  = 1 == 1 ? "Jhon" : "Ryan";
```

Is there anyway to make a parameter compulsory on condition ?

**The Codes Below Did Not Work, It's Here Just For The Example**

```
class Person{
  final String name;
  final int age; 
  const Person({ this.name, name != null ? @required this.age : this.age});
}
```

Comment: afaik you cannot do that, what you can use is `assert(...)` though

Comment: I would create different named constructors for different conditions with requirements set in each of them

Comment: @AlexRadzishevsky I thought so too, but want to know if there is way tho XD

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this.

You can have `assert`s checking conditions, but that would be runtime, not compile-time.

Your best way to make it happen is indeed having different named constructors for different purposes.

With the coming null-safety feature it would be a nightmare anyway. Not necessarily for the compiler, but for the programmer who has to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations like `@required` can only be added statically, and not depending on conditions.

To me this looks like a case for asserts as mentioned by @nvoigt

```dart
class Person{
  final String name;
  final int age; 
  const Person({ this.name, this.age}) : assert(name != null || age != null, "either name or age must be provided");
}
```